# XPath query for content between HTML tags

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I have HTML like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="{{find_this}}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>{{find_this}}</div>
    <span>{{find_this}}</span>
    <p>{{find_this}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I load this in a DOM document and XPath like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($template);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

I want to use xpath to query a tag that has `{{find_this}}` as value and no as attribute value. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean `no` as attribute value?  Are you looking for elements where only `content`  attributes equals `{{find_this}}`, or any attribute with that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath expression,

```
//*[.='{{find_this}}']
```

will select all elements (not attributes) whose string value ***equals*** `{{find_this}}`.

Alternatively, if you wish to select all elements whose string value ***contains*** the string, use this XPath:

```
//*[contains(.,'{{find_this}}')]
```